# Changing values in list to values in {} in Python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary where the value is in list

```
zoo_dict = {'bird': ['penguin', 'ostrich'], 'reptile': ['snake', 'chameleon']}
```

How do to change the list of values into {values}?

```
zoo_dict = {'bird': {'penguin', 'ostrich'}, 'reptile': {'snake', 'chameleon'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are sets. Use a dictionary-comprehension:

```
zoo_dict = {'bird': ['penguin', 'ostrich'], 'reptile': ['snake', 'chameleon']} 

zoo_dict = {k: set(v) for k, v in zoo_dict.items()}

print(zoo_dict)
```

Result:

```
zoo_dict = {'bird': {'penguin', 'ostrich'}, 'reptile': {'snake', 'chameleon'}}
```